# Can't get the C# implementation of gRPC to work on my m1 Mac

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc, apple-m1, grpc-c#

1. the situation:
   I'm trying to implement gRPC on simple csharp console app on my m1 MacBook
2. the problem:
   I need to use the old gRPC implementation specifically with my csharp console app the one that uses the native c library instead of the new modern csharp grpc implementation ( because I wanna the server to be a console csharp app instead of being an asp.net web app).
   but it seems that there is no native gRPC c library available for m1 right now, thus I cannon run my code
3. what I have tried:
   I installed the following dependencies `Grpc.Core`, `Grpc.Core.Api`, `Grpc.Tools`, `Google.protobuf` via the NuGet Package Manager and finally installed the package `Contrip.Grpc.Core.M1` which works just fine at the beginning but later it doesn't ever seems to be working again
4. what I wanna do to solve the problem:
   I installed the gRPC native c library via home-brew and the csharp console app doesn't seems to be able to automatically detect and use installed gRPC package via the home-brew, so my question is how can I make my csharp console app know exactly where does the gRPC c library located in my system

Answer (score 0):

The gRPC C# implementation based on that native grpc-core libraries is in maintenance and should not be used for new applications.

You can use the new grpc-dotnet C# implemenation, and the server can run as a command line app (a "console" app). See the tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio-mac